# Pandas: If column value is empty then insert value from another column in the same row

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the following scenario where I need to fill my empty column value with another column value.

my.csv

```
country    newCountry
France      Argentina
Uruguay     
Germany     Ireland
```

desired output:

```
country    newCountry
France      Argentina
Uruguay     Uruguay
Germany     Ireland
```

my code:

```
 df.loc[df['newCountry'] == '', 'newCountry'] = df['country']
```

it doesn't throw any error, but after running this the row value remains empty instead of show Uruguay in the newCountry column.

Could someone help with this please?

Answer (score 2):

If possible mutiple spaces use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df.loc[df['newCountry'].str.strip() == '', 'newCountry'] = df['country']
```

Or if there are missing values instead empty space use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['newCountry'] = df['newCountry'].fillna(df['country'])
```